# Vaadin animator fades in goes away on refresh

Tags: java, vaadin, animator

I am using Vaadin Animator 2.0.0 add on to fade-in the component. I am using following code

```
new Dom(referenceLayout).getStyle().opacity(0);
Animator.animate(referenceLayout, new Css().opacity(1.0)).delay(100).duration(2000);
```

it works fine, but if I refresh the page, I understand the second line (Animator) doesn't kick in and by default, the component remains with 0 opacity and I dont see anything.
What can I do to make sure the component remains visible even after the refresh. I dont care if the animator kicks in after refresh or not.

Comment: Do you have @PreserveOnRefresh in your UI class? The Animator doesn’t store the animations in its state, so once it has run an animation, it doesn’t remember it for following reloads/repaints, unless your animation code is run in connection to UI.init() and you don’t specify "PreserveOnRefresh".

Comment: I have @PreserveOnRefresh in my UI class. Can I apply regular CSS fade-in in DOM?

Comment: If you just need to fade-in a component, then a simple CSS keyframe animation is enough. You don’t necessarily need the Animator add-on for that.

Comment: can you point me to an example, how to achieve that using CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a simple fade-in animation for a component, you can do the following (assuming you are using/extending the Valo theme):

Your app:

```
mycomponent.addStyleName("fade-in");
```

Your theme:

```
.fade-in {
  @include valo-animate-in-fade;
}
```

For further documentation about the animation mixins in the Valo theme, see the documentation at https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#animation

Comment: I used the above but I dont see any effect?

Comment: can you please tell me how to make it work? if you an provide me complete CSS